# C Beginner: Does scanf "receive" the EOF marker from standard input?

Tags: c, stdin, eof

I would like to know if scanf is capable of receiving the EOF marker from standard input the same way getchar can. What I have below is only a very small sample of my code, but if this code were to be executed, would the EOF marker be the last char in the array?

```
#include "stdio.h"

char userInput[1200];
printf("Enter your input: ");
scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", userInput);
```

Comment: What happens when you print the numerical value of every array element?

Comment: "*... marker*" it's not a marker, it's a change in state. `EOL` is *not* a character. If any function returns `EOL` it just tells you: "No more data to come!"

Comment: "... would the EOF marker be the last char in the array?" --> No. Read  [scanf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html)

Answer (score 2):

You should read the documentation instead of asking here. You would know that `scanf()` and family not only has a return value but also it's extremely useful.

The return value of `scanf()` is used to tell how many format specifiers did the input match and it can eventually return `EOF` too, so checking the return value from `scanf()` is mandatory and YES it will return `EOF` if you press the right combination of keys.

Comment: Alright, now that I know that scanf is capable of receiving EOF, I have another question. Let's say I have a variable that stores the number of elements currently in the array. If I want to use a while loop to continually accept input until it detects EOF, would the condition of the while loop be: 'while (userInput[numArrayElements] != EOF)' ?

Comment: @Proto: [read the documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) --- [read the documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) --- [read the documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) --- [read the documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) --- [read the documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html).

Comment: @Proto: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40072576/c-beginner-does-scanf-receive-the-eof-marker-from-standard-input#comment67419064_40072576

Comment: regarding your new question, the EOF will not be in the array.  It is one of the possible returned values (no a parameter value) from the call to `scanf()`   I.E.  `if( EOF == scanf( "%d", &myarray[x] ) )` // then END OF FILE event encountered